# Managing FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi i am working on a calling app based on webRtc. Calling activity opens with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS and its working fine.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_IS_INCOMING_CALL, isIncomingCall);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is When my app is in recent app list and an incoming call comes Call activity opens with above intent . After finishing the CallActivity the app left on the scrreen, it should not, cause CallActivity is triggered when app in in recent app list .
If anyone got the problem let me advise something to acheive it.Let me know in comments below if need more explanation on problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was I checked the whether app was in recent or newly opened.
I case of app was in recent stack i send it to back stack again by moveTaskToBack.

```
  moveTaskToBack(true);
```